# Sites 9.6 folder publishing localization behavior

Tags: sites-9.6

I understand that Tridion Sites 9.6 introduces both the ability to publish a folder (to queue any "dynamic" Components contained within the folder) as well as a new option to to make folders "non publishable."

Two questions come to mind for this nice new feature:

1. Is the "non publishable" option specific to (any) localized versions of the folder or is it set once across the BluePrint?
2. Is the "non publishable" option set per folder or is there some type of "inheritance" option similar to permissions. Here I mean *inheritance* as in folder hierarchy and folder nesting rather than BluePrinting.